# Why do the standard errors of logistic regression blow up with many zeros in response?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, econometrics, fixed-effects-model

I am working on a fixed-effects model where the response is the number of successes in $N$ trials. I noticed that when the number of successes is $0$ for a large number of units the standard error blows up. Why is that happening and will it affect the estimates of other coefficients?

Reproducible R code below.

```r
set.seed(123456)

units <- c(1:10)
time <- c(1, 2)

# Create design matrix
X <- expand.grid(units = units, time = time)

# Create response
trials <- trunc(runif(nrow(X), 100, 1000))
successes <- rep(0, length(trials))

non_zeros <- 3
non_zeros_index <- sample(1:length(successes), non_zeros)

successes[sample(1:length(successes), non_zeros)] <- 
    trunc(runif(non_zeros, 2, 10))

y <- as.matrix(data.frame(successes = successes, 
               failures = trials - successes))

# Fit model
m <- glm(y ~ factor(units), data = X, family = binomial())

summary(m)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mostly fitting machine imprecision with this model. Here are the data, based on the provided code:

```r
    cbind(y,units)
    #      successes failures units
    # [1,]         0      818     1
    # [2,]         7      771     2
    # [3,]         0      452     3
    # [4,]         0      407     4
    # [5,]         0      425     5
    # [6,]         0      278     6
    # [7,]         0      581     7
    # [8,]         0      186     8
    # [9,]         0      989     9
    #[10,]         0      250    10
    #[11,]         0      818     1
    #[12,]         0      634     2
    #[13,]         0      914     3
    #[14,]         9      883     4
    #[15,]         9      985     5
    #[16,]         0      906     6
    #[17,]         0      890     7
    #[18,]         0      277     8
    #[19,]         0      401     9
    #[20,]         0      799    10
```

There are no successes associated with the reference level `units = 1`, whose log odds provide the intercept. That intercept, from `summary(m)` is:

```r
    Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
    (Intercept)       -26.4016  8109.4765  -0.003    0.997
```

for odds (and, effectively, success probability) of

```r
    exp(-26.4016)
    # [1] 3.41925e-12
```

although you know that the actual success probability for that factor level is 0. The other coefficients represent *differences* from the log odds of the intercept, so it's not surprising that they have large standard errors, even for the 3 levels of `units` that actually have successes.

Things make a bit more sense if you choose a factor level with some successes as reference:

```r
    m2 <- glm(y ~ relevel(factor(units),ref="2"), data = X, 
                   family = binomial())
```

and look at the first few rows of coefficients from `summary(m2)`:

```r
    Coefficients:
                                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept)                           -5.3019     0.3789 -13.993   <2e-16 ***
    relevel(factor(units), ref = "2")1   -21.0997  8109.4765  -0.003    0.998    
    relevel(factor(units), ref = "2")3   -20.8594  7870.1298  -0.003    0.998    
    relevel(factor(units), ref = "2")4     0.3367     0.5054   0.666    0.505    
    relevel(factor(units), ref = "2")5     0.2478     0.5054   0.490    0.624    
    relevel(factor(units), ref = "2")6   -20.6136  7475.7834  -0.003    0.998
```

Here you have reasonable values and acceptable standard errors for the intercept and for the coefficients of levels of `units` that actually have successes.

The large standard errors of the coefficient estimates are related to division by something close to 0, with near-[perfect separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11109/28500). Following Agresti's description in [*Categorical Data Analysis, 2nd Edition*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/0471249688), Chapter 5, with $N$ sets of observations having distinct combinations of $p$ predictors, let $X$ be the $N\times p$ matrix of predictor values, $n_i$ the number of cases for the $i^{th}$ set of distinct combinations of predictor values, $\hat\pi_i$ the estimated success probability for predictor-value set $i$, and $\hat\beta$ the vector of coefficient estimates.

Quoting from Agresti, page 194:

> The estimated covariance matrix ... has form
>
> $$\widehat {\text{cov}}(\hat \beta) = \left[X'\text{diag}[n_i\hat \pi_i(1-\hat\pi_i)]X\right]^{-1}$$
>
> where $\text{diag}[n_i\hat\pi_i(1-\hat\pi_i)]$ denotes the $N\times N$ diagonal matrix having $[n_i  \hat \pi_i(1-\hat \pi_i)]$ on
> the main diagonal.

The individual coefficient standard errors are the square roots of the diagonal elements of that covariance matrix. If there are no successes for a particular predictor-value set $i$, then the corresponding element of $\text{diag}[n_i\hat\pi_i(1-\hat\pi_i)]$ will be 0 (or very close to it, as in the OP). The information matrix $X'\text{diag}[n_i\hat \pi_i(1-\hat\pi_i)]X$ could be ill-conditioned, and its inverse, the estimated coefficient covariance matrix, will then show this type of problem.